# React Searchbar. Can´t select data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, searchbar

I´ve got some problems with my react Searchbar, but I don´t understand why. The app is quite simple, it just gets some data from an API, and shows it under the input. The next thing I want to implement, is that I can click the Content and it gets past into the Searchbar. I want to handle it with a onClick event, but every time I want to execute it, I get an error that my function (select) is not defined. I guess somthings wrong with the render of the Stock-Symbols. I am a react/programming beginner, so I would appreciate every form of help :)

Heres my code:

```
const Searchbar = () => {
const [stockSymbol, setStockSymbol] = useState('')




const searchInput = useRef();
const listSymbol = useRef();
const inputRef = useRef();
const results = useRef();
const API_KEY = "KT7CW1QXDZBDGCIH.";



useEffect(() => {
onChange();
}, [stockSymbol])

//set Value of Input equal to selected Stock 
function select(element){
      let selectData = element.textContent
      inputRef.value = selectData
    }

 // Search Endpoint - Fetch Data from API

function onChange (){ 
   let APISymbol  = []
  
   
  if(stockSymbol !== '') {
   
    let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=${stockSymbol}&apikey=${API_KEY}`

    fetch(API_Call)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function (data) {
        // get an Array of 5 suggestions

       for(var key=0; key < 5; key++){

         // push everything in Var APISymbol
           APISymbol.push(data['bestMatches'][key]['1. symbol'])
           console.log(key)
       }

       // Map through List of suggestions and transform them into HTML
       let stockList = APISymbol.map((data)=> {
         return data = `<li class="symbols" ref={listSymbol} onClick={select}>` + data + `</li>`
       })
       console.log(stockList)

       //add active so Symbol gets displayed
       document.getElementById('search-input').classList.add('active')

       // displays Symbol in Searchbar
       document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = stockList.join('')

    }).catch ((err) => alert(err) )
  }else{

  //if nothing is in Searchbar, don´t display it
document.getElementById('search-input').classList.remove('active') }
}



return (
        <div>
          <div ref={searchInput} id='search-input' className='search-input'> 
            <input ref = {inputRef} className = 'searchbar' type='text' placeholder='Searchbar...'  onKeyUp  = {(e) => {setStockSymbol(e.target.value.toUpperCase())}}/>
           {stockSymbol !== '' && <div ref={results} className="results" id='results'>
           
            </div>}
          </div>  
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Searchbar
```

Tank you!

Answer (score 0):

You use the below code, you do not need any backtick **`** and string concatenation because in React those are jsx which is a wrapper on javascript, so the plain writing is correct.

```
let stockList = APISymbol.map((data)=> {
         return <li class="symbols" ref={listSymbol} onClick={select}>data</li>;
       })
```

You take another state

```
const [apiSymbol, setApiSymbol ] = useState([])

function onChange (){ 
   let APISymbol  = []
  
   
  if(stockSymbol !== '') {
   
    let API_Call = `https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=${stockSymbol}&apikey=${API_KEY}`

    fetch(API_Call)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function (data) {
        // get an Array of 5 suggestions

       for(var key=0; key < 5; key++){

         // push everything in Var APISymbol
           APISymbol.push(data['bestMatches'][key]['1. symbol'])
           console.log(key)
       }

       setApiSymbol(prevData => APISymbol);

    }).catch ((err) => alert(err) )
  }else{

  //if nothing is in Searchbar, don´t display it
document.getElementById('search-input').classList.remove('active') }
}

const renderApiSymvbol = () => {
   return APISymbol.map((data)=> {
         return <li class="symbols" ref={listSymbol} onClick={select}>data</li>;
       })
}
```

Return block

```
return (
        <div>
          <div ref={searchInput} id='search-input' className='search-input'> 
            <input ref = {inputRef} className = 'searchbar' type='text' placeholder='Searchbar...'  onKeyUp  = {(e) => {setStockSymbol(e.target.value.toUpperCase())}}/>
           {stockSymbol !== '' && renderApiSymbol()}
          </div>  
            
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answere! But that dosn´t work. If I use your code I just get some empty objects back.

Comment: Sorry but that dosn´t work for me. Why do you need another state? If i copy your code I get alot of errors...

Comment: Please check now, I updated the code. We need extra state because when you receive data from API then only render based on the received data. Unless you have state, react will not rerender the component.